# Adding a Header to and NSArray for a Dynamic Table cell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, ios4

```
[super viewDidLoad];

self.Lodgelist = [[NSArray alloc]
                  initWithObjects:@"Sterling ",
                  @"Sterling location  1234",
                  @"Sterling  location 12345",nil];
```

This is an example of my code. I would like the header to be the city name "Sterling" I am new to objective-c. Thanks again for the help.

P.S I am not sure how or were to add the code.

Comment: In short are you want to adding the Header into the UITableview?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a 1x3(one column) table with the column header "Sterling "?

Comment: I want to set a header for the list above. the NSArray is in a dynamic grouped table cell. I want each group to have a different header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add UITableViewDelegate in header of your ViewController, then add the below code to change the header of your UITableView

```
 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

    {
         return [self.Lodgelist objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

Comment: When you say the header is that under the #import or @implementation? of the .m viewcontroller

Comment: @interface URViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> in viewController .h file

Comment: Im getting "Expected identifier or ')' " error at the first {

Comment: Im new to all this coding.. how should it look?

Comment: can you do the same for an Array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set only title to header then use

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [self.Lodgelist objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

and if you want to add some image and other thing to section header (or some view) then use

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: Im trying to place a header for each different NSArray that I have.. I have a few locations in each city. I want each city to be grouped and list the locations

Comment: Where do I put that code? here is what I have now.  for my list of locations. I want to give it a header title.    
    self.Lodgelist = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"Sterling Lodge 123",
                      @"Sterling Lodge 1234",
                      @"Serling Lodge 12345",nil];

Comment: i dont understand what are you saying now?